# How to set up Windows user account profile folder to be readable by another user account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, user-profiles

My goal is to set up permissions on a user account profile to be readable by another user. I'm setting up such scheme for an automated backup purpose.

So, say I have two standard user accounts -- `User A` that is a general user of the system, whose data will be backed up:

[image]

And `BackupUser` that will be doing the backing up:

[image]

I want to set up permissions on the `User A`'s profile folder `C:\Users\User A` to be readable by `BackupUser`.

So I start a `cmd` as administrator and run the following [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx) command:

```
icacls "C:\Users\User A" /t /c /l /q /grant DESKTOP-69AQNQQ\BackupUser:(RX)
```

But it fails with errors of access denied to some folders.

OK. So I downloaded [PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) and first run my `cmd` as `SYSTEM` hoping to prevent access denied errors:

```
PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD
```

and then run the same command from it. But it still gives me the same errors:

[image]

So as a result when I try to copy the `C:\Users\User A` folder from a process running under `BackupUser` user account it fails with, you guessed it, "access denied" error.

So what am I doing wrong here?

PS. I'm doing these tests on Windows 10 Pro.

PS2. Here's the result of running `whoami` on the `cmd` prompt that I use for this:

[image]

PS3: And here's the output for `icacls "C:\users\User A\Documents"`:

[image]

Comment: Can you try it with GUI? Right click user folder, and give permissions for read and execute.

Comment: What's the output of `icacls "C:\users\User A\Documents"`? Administrators should have full access to this. If they have, your cmd.exe doesn't run elevated, check with `whoami /groups`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: I updated my OP with the `whoami` result.

Comment: All the "folders" it fails on are actually junctions that are only there for compatibility with older applications. You're not missing any data by not backing them up.

Comment: @BenN: Hmm. That's interesting. Good point. Although, you see my issue is that when I try to copy `C:\users\User A` it fails because that folder contains those junctions that `User A` doesn't have read-access to. There must be a way to set read permissions on them from the `SYSTEM` account, right?